# How to handle belongs to and has many relationship in Backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have two models, User and Picture. User has many Pictures. I want to make a suspend call to backend server query on Picture. Currently when I hit the suspend button I get the User model but I want picture model. In my User view I have following code.

**USER VIEW**

```
class MyApp.Views.User extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->
    @listenTo(@model, 'change',  @render)
    @listenTo(@model, 'destroy', @remove)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(user: @model))
    @fetchPictures()
    this

  fetchPictures: ->
    @picture_collection = new MyApp.Collections.Pictures()
    @picture_collection.fetch({ 
    reset: true, 
    data: { "user_id": @model.get("objectId") }#,
    success: (e) ->
      for picture in e.models
        view = new MyApp.Views.Picture(model: picture)
        $("#objects-info").html(view.render().el)
    })
```

**PICTURE VIEW**

```
class MyApp.Views.Picture extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['flagged_objects/picture']
  el: 'td'
  events: ->
    "click #Picure": "deletePicture"

  initialize: ->
    @model.set('id', this.model.get('objectId'))
    @listenTo(@model, 'change',  @render)
    @listenTo(@model, 'destroy', @remove)

  render: ->
    $("#object-info").append(@template(entry: @model))
    this

  deletePicture: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log @
```

**PICTURE COLLECTION**

```
class MyApp.Collections.Pictures extends Backbone.Collection
  model: MyApp.Models.Picture
  url: "/api/pictures"
```

**PICUTRE MODEL**

```
class MyAdmin.Models.Picture extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: 'api/picture'
  idAttribute: 'objectId'
```

In **USER VIEW** in @model variable I get User model. Is there any way to get Picture model here so that I can send call to suspend the picture.

In summary I just want to suspend picture model obejct from collection when I press suspend button. Suspend essentially is an update call.

Thanks,

Comment: You can have a look to http://backbonerelational.org/

Comment: I believe solution can be much simpler than this. I just want to trigger action related to model being clicked.

Comment: Why don't you move the deletePicture function to your picture sub-view?

Comment: I have moved deletePicture to picture sub-view and also defined el. Now I am starting to get click events registered but when I click the top most suspend button the deletePicture function is called for all objects in the collection except the one that is clicked. If I click the second suspended button the deletePicture function is called for all objects in the collection except for the 1st object and the one that is clicked and so on. I have also updated code please review again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as we have spoken in the comments, the deletePicture function should be in the Picture sub-view as what you want to suspend is a Picture model.

I think the strange behaviour you are having it's related to the way you are rendering your views.

In the user view you should append the Picture sub-views.

```
fetchPictures: ->
  @picture_collection = new MyApp.Collections.Pictures()
  @picture_collection.fetch({ 
  reset: true, 
  data: { "user_id": @model.get("objectId") }#,
  success: (e) ->
    for picture in e.models
      view = new MyApp.Views.Picture(model: picture)
      $("#objects-info").append(view.render().el)
  })
```

And it's in the render of the sub-view where you get access to the html function.

```
render: ->
  this.$el.html(@template(entry: @model))
  this
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: This only shows the last rendered picture element while overriding all before it. But the clicking suspend button still returns all the elements in collection.

Comment: "#objects-info" is a table?

Comment: "#objects-info" is a div while "#object-info" is a table.

Comment: So you should append the sub-views to "#object-info" although I'm not sure if the problem is there.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I will advise everyone to never use table.

Comment: What you could do also it's to create another view for the pictures collection. Then in your user view you have to initialize this pictures view with the pictures collection and inside of that pictures view is where you append every picture view.